# polymer element nested template not injected to dom

Tags: templates, data-binding, polymer, web-component

I'm trying to create element with this code

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/iron-ajax/iron-ajax.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-submenu/paper-submenu.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-item/paper-item.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/paper-menu/paper-menu.html">

<dom-module id="side-menu-element">
    <template>
        <style></style>
        <iron-ajax id="iron-ajax" auto url="side-menu-element-data-en.json" handle-as="json" last-response="{{handleResponse}}"></iron-ajax>
        <template is="dom-repeat" items="{{handleResponse.menus}}" as="menu">
            <paper-submenu label="[[menu.name]]">
                <paper-item class="menu-trigger">[[menu.name]]</paper-item>
                <paper-menu class="menu-content sublist2">
                    <template is="dom-repeat" items="[[menu.items]]" as="in-depth-menu">
                        <paper-item class="leaf">
                            <a href="[[in-depth-menu.address]]" title="[[in-depth-menu.topic]]">[[in-depth-menu.topic]]</a>
                        </paper-item>
                    </template>
                </paper-menu>
            </paper-submenu>
        </template>
    </template>
    <script>
        (function() {
            'use strict';

            Polymer({
                is: 'side-menu-element',

                properties: {
                }

            });
        })();
    </script>
</dom-module>
```

and it's just showing a template element in the inspector like this

```
<template is="dom-repeat" class="style-scope side-menu-element"></template>
```

it suppose to grape data from the json file and inject it to paper-submenu,paper-menu and paper-item. in the documentation there is no manipulation to data retrieved by the iron-ajax element from the json file just binding it to the other elements

Comment: Have you confirmed that the `iron-ajax` call is actually receiving a response?

Comment: i think it's received because the file is shown in the network tab

Comment: it worked and this is weird because all i did is removing the comments and unneeded spaces from the json file. sounds crazy , I know, but this is what happened despite I used a json validator before an it was approved.